# Cakephp2 form doesn't function redirect to the confirm page

Tags: forms, validation, cakephp-2.0

I'm new to  this community and I wanted to ask you about the cakephp2's validation and the form.
 I have a method called input() and this method is intended to send the forms variable to the confirm page. But the problem is that even I  press he submit button it doesn't go to the confirm page.
Here is the script but I'm not sure why it is working? It would be great if you can help me out!

```
public function input() {
    $this->title = 'contact';

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
                //die(1);
        $data = arrayWithKeys(
            $this->request->data['Contact'],
            array('name', 'email', 'contact_category', 'message'));
        $this->Contact->set($data);
        $ret = $this->Contact->validates();
                     //die(3);
        if ($ret) {
            $this->Session->write(self::SES_CONTACT_INFO, $data);

            $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'contacts', 'action' => 'confirm'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(
                $this->Contact->getValidationErrorsAsHtml(), 'error');
        }
                   // die(4);
    } else {
        $contact = $this->Session->read(self::SES_CONTACT_INFO);
        if ($contact) {
            $this->request->data['Contact'] = $contact;
        }
    }

    $this->set('contact_categories', $this->Contact->ContactCategory->find('list'));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For auth set up the basics like the sample below. And for redirecting use something like

$this->redirect(array('action' => 'edit', 5));

```
// 1.Basic setup
$this->Auth->authenticate = array('Form');

// Pass settings in
$this->Auth->authenticate = array(
    'Basic' => array('userModel' => 'Member'),
    'Form' => array('userModel' => 'Member')
);

// Pass settings in using 'all'
$this->Auth->authenticate = array(
    AuthComponent::ALL => array('userModel' => 'Member'),
    'Basic',
    'Form'
);
```

Comment: I've changed the setup and the sample you provided gave me a hint to what to do !